# Screen dependent image resolution

Tags: application-development, resolution, screen, ubuntu-touch, phone

I'm currently reading some articles about QML, QtQuick and the soon coming Ubuntu SDK and I'm wondering if there are any mechanism that allow a device resolution dependent selection of image resolutions.

For example Android provides a very simple directory structure that differentiate between low resolution devices and high resolution devices, so I just ship different version of the same image with my app and android decides which is the best one for the currently used device.

So the question is how I could support different screen resolutions in applications that use images as backgrounds or button labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QML toolkit will down-scale images to meet your resolution-independent size, see the Bitmaps section on http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/resolution-independence.html

Comment: So it is a good idea to use "high" resolution images? That's much payload for mobile apps isn't it? And the down-scaling will slow down apps which is very problematic on the entry level Ubuntu smartphones.  

_For example, if the destination size of the bitmap is 10 gu * 10 gu and the developer targets a smart phone with 4 inch HD (720x1,280px) screen (1 gu = 18 px) and a tablet with 10 inch HD screen (1 gu = 10 px) then he/she only needs to create a bitmap of 180 px * 180 px to support both devices._

180x180px is a very large image for a small icon ... :-(

Comment: If you want an icon that is 10 grid units per side, and a screen with 18 pixels per grid unit, then 180 pixels per side is exactly the size you're after.  If it's a small icon, you probably don't want it to be displayed using 10 grid units.